# Is there a way to merge two .gcda files into one?

Tags: code-coverage, gcov

I have several unit tests for an application, each of which is capable of generating .gcda files. I would like to be able to generate unified .gcda files which represent the coverage of my test suite as a whole. There doesn't appear to be an easy way to do this, but I could be wrong, and that's why I'm asking.

[With gcov, is it possible to merge to .gcda files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166198/with-gcov-is-it-possible-to-merge-to-gcda-files) was previously asked and the solution was to convert to lcov .info files and merge that way. If possible, I would like the output of the merge operation to still be a single .gcda file so that I'm not forced to use lcov.

Answer (score 4):

There is code to merge `.gcda` files but unfortunately it's buried in `libgcov.a` which builds as part of gcc.  If you exit (or in any way invoke `__gcov_flush()`) a program compiled with coverage it will actually detect pre-existing `.gcda` files, load them, aggregate their data with the running program's data, and save it back out.  I don't know of any tool which provides that functionality at the command line.  Even with `libgcov.a` you probably have no useful hooks to do what you want and would have to take the source from the gcc-core distribution and modify it.

What I have done in the past is just extract all the data to annotated source (`.gcov`) and aggregate at that level.  The `.gcda` format is capable of storing a lot more than line coverage information (eg branch counts) and the `libgcov.a` aggregation knows how to combine those (for some it's not as simple as summation).

Answer (score 2):

Gcov package comes with `gcov-tool` executable which is capable of merging gcda files:

```
gcov-tool merge dir1 dir2
```

(position of .gcda files *within* dirN must be identical). Resulting .gcda will be stored in the `merged_profile` directory (can be overriden with `-o` flag).

`Gcov-tool` is mainly meant to be used with series of .gcda files generated with `GCOV_PREFIX` or `-fprofile-dir=XXX.%p`.

Gcov-tool can merge only two profiles at a time but you can use a wrapper [gcov-tool-many](https://github.com/yugr/maintainer-scripts/blob/master/gcov-tool-many) to circumvent this.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! What does "position must be identical" mean? If I happen to have a directory structure with the `.gcda` distributed across it, it expects the files with the same names to be at the same location in that tree?

Comment: @thoni56 yes, exactly: files with same names must be in same relative locations inside combined directories.

Comment: It isn't documented so it might be risk to rely on, but it seems that it is possible to incrementally merge new sets into the original, like `gcov-tool merge dir1 dir -o dir ; gcov-tool merge dir2 dir -o dir; gcov-tool merge dir3 dir -o dir` simplifying this quite a bit. (Not to take away any merits from `gcov-tool-many`).

Comment: @thoni56 very nice!

Answer (score 1):

I have just created a test project which shows, AFAIKT, that when a single test application is run successively with different parameters, then the gcda files are updated between runs and running gcov once (I use [gcovr.py](http://gcovr.com/)) produces aggregate coverage information.