# Using Lcov in a cluster

Tags: c++, cluster-computing, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I am working in a C/C++ application which solves logical formulas. In order to make a coverage analysis I am using Gcov (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) executing it in a cluster/Grid and I am partially happy due to the fact that I can gather the information  I am interested in but on the other hand the presentation layer is difficult to get without big efforts in parsing data obtained.

So I decided to use Lcov (http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php) which allow to generate a html output based on the results, but even if I can execute Lcov locally in the user workstation I would like to use it in the cluster but I did not find yet a suitable way to execute LCov in the cluster, then gather the results of all the executions in all the nodes and finally generate the html output combining all the results.

Any suggestions regard my problem is welcomed!

Thanks in advance!

Best!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166198/with-gcov-is-it-possible-to-merge-to-gcda-files

Comment: Hi, after reading the post you post what I got is a very long report split by nodes, so I figured out that my needs are pretty different because what I have are not 2 execution environments but many application executables which execute in N computers in parallel, then I would like to find a way to merge the N *.info files into only one short report which respects the project structure.