# How to get coverage information for each run on Gcov (or Gcovr)?

Tags: gcc, gcov, lcov, gcovr

I'm trying to get coverage information for each of my test cases (and also the total coverage). But since `.gcda` file will be merged everytime the program runs, it's not possible unless the file is deleted/moved.

The problem of deleting the `.gcda` file for every new test case execution is that I have to repeat the whole process again in order to get the coverage information of all of my test cases. If I have 2000 test cases, I have to run my program 4000 times.

As for moving the `.gcda` file, I have to merge all of the `.gcda` files. Is it possible to merge multiple gcda files with Gcov (or Gcovr since I use it for the XML output)?

Apparently [lcov has a merging feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3372599/6220384) but AFAIK it doesn't support xml output.

Comment: I think `gcov-tool merge` can merge profiling data from two directories, but I'm not sufficiently familiar with it to write an answer. Note that gcov-tool seems to be younger than the question you linked.

Comment: @amon it works! I'm surprised I didn't get `gcov-tool` on any of my search result. it's quite simple to use but there are a couple of things that are not really clear to me like "weight factor" or "online/offline generated". Mind if you put it as your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You can self-answer with your experiences, or write an answer to the question you linked. This question can then be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`gcov` can merge coverage data from two runs with the help of `gcov-tool`:

```
$ gcov-tool merge dir1 dir2
```

(by default results will be stored into `merged_profile` folder).

One problem with `gcov-tool` is that it can only be applied to two directories at a time (whereas you seem to have thousands). You can use the [gcov-tool-many](https://github.com/yugr/maintainer-scripts/blob/master/gcov-tool-many) wrapper to work around this.